# Удаление повторяющихся строк

Tags: c#

Есть тхт в ней есть много строк...
все строки одинаковой длинны..
пример такой:

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

как удалить лишние но оставить одну оригинальную строку, то есть после работы кода будет так:

```
1
2
3
```

через массив ? А дальше хз...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(...).Distinct();
```

Comment: ничего не вышло..

Comment: Приведите свой код как вы проверяли

Comment: `static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\test.txt").Distinct();
        }`

Comment: Ну и как вы определили, что ничего не вышло?

Comment: размер файла не изменился, он должен был бы весить примерно в 70 раз меньше, а остался таким же

Comment: @Tode а вы измененные данные то в него обратно записали?

Comment: Так в вашем коде есть только чтение строк и выбор уникальных. Записи в файл в вашем коде нет.

Comment: А перезаписть будет
`File.WriteAllLines(path);` ?

Comment: Добавьте после чтения строчку: `File.WriteAllLines(..., lines);`

Answer (score 1):

Ну например

```
File.ReadLines(path).Distinct()
```

Comment: ничего не вышло..

Comment: @Tode: В каком смысле «не вышло»?

Comment: все гут.............